# PHP: Create arrays from a function call inside a foreach loop and merge them

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

The purpose of this code is to identify all the image files from the folder in which the code is being invoked in order to create an image gallery. The images are listed in alphanumeric order but I require a specific order so reordering with a standard PHP array sorting function doesn't meet my needs.

I am using an if statement to place image collections into different arrays then merging the arrays into my required order.

When I run the code as part of my foreach loop it works fine. I want to put the if conditional into a function to reuse the code but I just get a blank page when I copy and paste the code into the function:

```
// echo statements are just for testing.

foreach(glob(IMAGEPATH."*.{jpg,png,gif,JPG,PNG,GIF}", GLOB_BRACE) as $var03){
    $img_src03 = basename($var03);
    $img_label03 = pathinfo($var03, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    // Assign specific values to the arrays as you cycle through $img_src03 values:
    if (substr($img_src03, 0, 5) == 'ext_f'){
        if (!isset($array33)) {
            $array33 = array();
        }
        $array33[] = $img_src03;
        echo $img_src03 . ' : Image label = ' . img_label($img_label03) . '<br>';
    } elseif (substr($img_src03, 0, 5) == 'ext_r'){
        if (!isset($array33)) {
            $array33 = array();
        }
        $array33[] = $img_src03;
        echo $img_src03 . ' : Image label = ' . img_label($img_label03) . '<br>';
    } elseif (substr($img_src03, 0, 6) == 'ext_po'){
        if (!isset($array34)) {
            $array34 = array();
        }
        $array34[] = $img_src03;
        echo $img_src03 . ' : Image label = ' . img_label($img_label03) . '<br>';
    } elseif (substr($img_src03, 0, 3) == 'bed'){
        if (!isset($array35)) {
            $array35 = array();
        }
        $array35[] = $img_src03;
        echo $img_src03 . ' : Image label = ' . img_label($img_label03) . '<br>';
    } elseif (substr($img_src03, 0, 3) == 'bth'){
        if (!isset($array36)) {
            $array36 = array();
        }
        $array36[] = $img_src03;
        echo $img_src03 . ' : Image label = ' . img_label($img_label03) . '<br>';
    }
}
$arrayFinal = array_merge($array33, $array34, $array35, $array36);
echo 'This is $arrayFinal:<br><pre>'; print_r($arrayFinal);     echo '</pre><br>';
```

When the exact same if conditional is placed inside function findImage03($img_src03, $img_label03), which is located outside the foreach loop, then called from inside the foreach loop the code fails to work.

```
foreach(glob(IMAGEPATH."*.{jpg,png,gif,JPG,PNG,GIF}", GLOB_BRACE) as $var03){
    $img_src03 = basename($var03);
    $img_label03 = pathinfo($var03, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    // Trying to use a function call to run the if conditional. Function is outside the foreach loop. Nothing returned.
    findImage03($img_src03, $img_label03);
}

function findImage03($img_src03, $img_label03){
    // Assign specific values to the arrays as you cycle through $img_src03 values:
    if (substr($img_src03, 0, 5) == 'ext_f'){
        if (!isset($array33)) {
            $array33 = array();
        }
        $array33[] = $img_src03;
        echo $img_src03 . ' : Image label = ' . img_label($img_label03) . '<br>';
    } elseif (substr($img_src03, 0, 5) == 'ext_r'){
        if (!isset($array33)) {
            $array33 = array();
        }
        $array33[] = $img_src03;
        echo $img_src03 . ' : Image label = ' . img_label($img_label03) . '<br>';
    } elseif (substr($img_src03, 0, 6) == 'ext_po'){
        if (!isset($array34)) {
            $array34 = array();
        }
        $array34[] = $img_src03;
        echo $img_src03 . ' : Image label = ' . img_label($img_label03) . '<br>';
    } elseif (substr($img_src03, 0, 3) == 'bed'){
        if (!isset($array35)) {
            $array35 = array();
        }
        $array35[] = $img_src03;
        echo $img_src03 . ' : Image label = ' . img_label($img_label03) . '<br>';
    } elseif (substr($img_src03, 0, 3) == 'bth'){
        if (!isset($array36)) {
            $array36 = array();
        }
        $array36[] = $img_src03;
        echo $img_src03 . ' : Image label = ' . img_label($img_label03) . '<br>';
    }
}
$arrayFinal = array_merge($array33, $array34, $array35, $array36);
echo 'This is $arrayFinal:<br><pre>'; print_r($arrayFinal);     echo '</pre><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In researching this I think I have found a couple of issues so I'm not sure if this is down to not being a programmer or not.

1. I found a solution running foreach() in a function() rather than a function() within a foreach(). *The new array is then created using the result of the function call.*
2. array_merge() works only if all the arrays being merged hold values otherwise it fails. Not sure if that could be resolved with !isset.

So this is the code running the foreach() in a function() which can be located in an included file for reuse efficiency plus a single source to maintain/update:

```
// Define the function to get all the images in the current folder:
function getImages(){
    foreach(glob(IMAGEPATH."*.{jpg,png,gif,JPG,PNG,GIF}", GLOB_BRACE) as $var){
        $img_src = basename($var);
        
        // Assign specific values to the array as you cycle through the collection. Order here will not affect final array order.
        if (substr($img_src, 0, 5) == 'bed_1'){
            if (!isset($arrayBed_1)) {
                $arrayBed_1 = array();
            }
            $arrayBed_1[] = $img_src;
        } elseif (substr($img_src, 0, 5) == 'bed_2'){
            if (!isset($arrayBed_2)) {
                $arrayBed_2 = array();
            }
            $arrayBed_2[] = $img_src;
        } elseif (substr($img_src, 0, 5) == 'bed_3'){
            if (!isset($arrayBed_3)) {
                $arrayBed_3 = array();
            }
            $arrayBed_3[] = $img_src;
        // continue for each type required.
        }           }
    } //End of foreach().
    
    // Create the pre final array for other arrays to push to which defines the sort order:
    $arrayPreFinal = array();
    
    if (isset($arrayExt_f)){                        // ext_f = exterior front
        foreach ($arrayExt_f as $val){
            array_push($arrayPreFinal, $val);
        }
    }
    if (isset($arrayExt_r)){                        // ext_r = exterior rear
        foreach ($arrayExt_r as $val){
            array_push($arrayPreFinal, $val);
        }
    }
    if (isset($arrayBed_1)){                        // bed_1 = bedroom 1
        foreach ($arrayBed_1 as $val){
            array_push($arrayPreFinal, $val);
        }
    }
    if (isset($arrayBed_2)){                        // bed_2 = bedroom 2
        foreach ($arrayBed_2 as $val){
            array_push($arrayPreFinal, $val);
        }
    }
    // continue for as many variances as require.
    
    
    return $arrayPreFinal;
} // End of function()
```

The code run from the folder where the images are located:

```
// Set $iwd Image Working Directory:
// Required before gallery_ctrl_body.php inlcude as $iwd is needed before include.

// class IWD changes outside the class.
class IWD {
    // Properties
    public $iwd;
}
$var = new IWD();
$var->name = getcwd();
$iwd = $var->name;

// Script include needs to be run before function pid_text().
include_once ('../gallery_ctrl_body.php');

# Function to identify the property sub-division from directory path characters using preg_match()
# and define a Property ID Text:
function pid_text($sub_div) {       //Need parameter/s in function():
    $sub_div_abb = sub_div_abb($sub_div); //20200220 code
    $psc = 'ORL'; // Start of Property System Code.
    $str = getcwd();

    if(preg_match("/{$sub_div}/i", $str)) {
        $psc = $psc . $sub_div_abb . strtoupper(basename(__DIR__)); //sub_div_abb may already defined in UPPERCASE.
        $pid_textname = constant("PROPERTY_TEXT") . $psc; //strtoupper($psc);
    }
    return $pid_textname;                   //Return value AFTER IF statement. REQUIRED!
}   
$pid_text = pid_text($sub_div = 'test_200828');
    
// Define the imagepath and variables:
define('IMAGEPATH', dirname(__FILE__).'/'); // '/' is required.
$img_height = 'height: 400px'; // default image height for gallery.
$img_width = 'width: 600px'; // default image width for gallery.
$img_counter = 0;
$img_style = 'style="' .  $img_width . '"'; // only needs to be set once here.
$img_total = 0;

// Create the final array with function call to get images:
$arrayFinal = getImages();

// Calculate total number of images before displaying <div>
// If calculated inside a foreach() $img_counter always equals $img_total.
$img_total = count($arrayFinal);

echo '<div class="property_text-container">';
    echo 'Gallery for ' . $pid_text;
echo '</div>';

//<!-- Slideshow container -->
echo '<div class="slideshow-container">';

// foreach ($array1 as $value){
foreach ($arrayFinal as $value){
    $img_counter ++; // Set before function() when using function call.
    // Call the function located in gallery_ctrl_body:
    createGallery($img_width, $img_style, $filename, $img_name, $img_src, $img_counter, $img_total, $value, $pid_text);
}

// <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
echo '<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>';
echo '<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a> ';

echo '</div>';
// <!-- END: div class="slideshow-container"-->
echo '<br>';

// <!-- Dot container -->
echo '<div class="dot-container">';
    // <!-- The dots/circles -->
    echo '<div style="text-align:center">';
        $slide_counter = 0;
        while ($slide_counter < $img_total) {
            $slide_counter ++;
            echo '<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(' . $slide_counter . ')"></span>&nbsp;';
        }
    echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';

// Script include needs to be run at end of page including it.
include_once ('../gallery_ctrl_script.php');
```

So, this code works but I'm not sure if it's the correct way or approach. If works for me as I have a set image naming convention and my galleries can be controlled from a single source file. It will work for any number of images, if they exist, in the folder where the function is being called from although my properties generally will have less than 50.